# I am getting exception-org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke threw exception java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security

I am getting the following error in my server log,

```
08-May-2018 12:00:07.460 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:211)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:109)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:109)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.getWriter(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:149)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:111)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:176)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:120)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.uncaughtException_html._jspService(uncaughtException_html.java:209)


    08-May-2018 12:00:07.468 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [xyz] in context with path [] threw exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response] with root cause java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response     
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:211)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:109)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:109)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.getWriter(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:149)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:111)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:176)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:120)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.uncaughtException_html._jspService(uncaughtException_html.java:209)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
```

I do not know which method is throwing this error and what is the cause of this error. Actually this exception occured at the time when I deployed my application in tomcat and trying to get index page(Sometime first time, sometime second, sometime third the point is it comes no matter when it comes.), actually according to my configuration when ssl is enabled and when I deploy my application and trying to get welcome page session expired page is called and from now once I tried to get some other pages it throws the above exception. I am using spring 4 ,spring security, maven, hibernate 4.  Can any one help me? Any Help will be appriciated.

**web.xml**

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>Smart app Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml, /WEB-INF/app-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/views/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>application</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>50</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: The answer to your problem may lie here `java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response] with root cause java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response`

It seems that someone has already consumed the response's outputstream once and then someone else is attempting to do the same (hence the IllegalArgumentException). I would suggest going through your code and checking for occurrences on this pattern.

Comment: @Aris i searched in entire workspace for getOutputStream() and just got one occurence of it, and then i commented that code but exception still occurs.

Comment: trying looking for getWriter too

Comment: @Aris, 0 occurence of getWriter

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540464/java-lang-illegalstateexception-getoutputstream-has-already-been-called-for-t 
It should help you understand the exception.

Comment: are there multiple synchronized webapp in tomcat container for this project? sometime this issue called by catalina also

Comment: @this_is_om_vm no

Comment: adapt new version of tomcat too.

Comment: @this_is_om_vm already i have 8.5.

Comment: once can you try with the any other version of tomcat.As i try to reproduce the above problem but it's working fine on tomcat 8.0

Comment: @this_is_om_vm No luck same problem

Comment: CAn you put the code where you comment the outputstream?

Comment: Are you using jstl?

Comment: @Gatusko yes i am using jstl

Comment: Ok Please add that index.jsp and the JSTL, because maybe you are using and out when you closed the stream.

Comment: @Gatusko link for index : https://github.com/ManojLucky/ExamAppLocal.git

Comment: I had a similar problem caused by an bidirectional ManyToMany relationship using jackson for JSON serialization. I had  to put JsonIgnore annotation in one side.

Comment: there is a line in the stacktrace. org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.uncaughtException_html._jspService. It might be possible that some jsp failed and the original exception is somehow hidden by this exception which is come while handling the first exception.

Comment: @NorbertoRitzmann I don't have ManyToMany relationship

Comment: @gagansingh Actually i have SimpleMappingExceptionResolver configured with defaultErrorView "uncaughtException" so any suggestion.

Comment: Ok, but could be any cyclical relationship, like Order -> Product -> Order...Not exacly ManyToMany.

Comment: If you have and SimpleMappingExceptionResolver you could have conflicts with in ControllerAdvice with ExceptionHandler annotation

Comment: @NorbertoRitzmann yes i have conflict in ControllerAdvice. Problem resolved.

Comment: @NorbertoRitzmann  I think you can answer to the question so I can accept as correct answer. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a SimpleMappingExceptionResolver try to check if you have conflicts with your ControllerAdvice annotated class. Exceptions have to be handled only in one place.

As I said, it could be generated by a cyclical in relationship and Jackason as serializer too. In this you have some options like use a DTO that simplifies the answer or user @JsonIgnore.